# A good memorandum template for LaTeX

Tags: templates

Pretty much the title says it all ... does anyone know of a good memorandum template (with an example maybe?).

You know, the things companies print on their text and stuff before faxing them out. It is usually composed of a letterhead on top (a logo on the left is optional), and some accounts and banking data in small letters on the bottom of the document.

In the middle, goes your text.

I'm rather unexperienced in composing LaTeX documents, but I have to make a memo and want it to look rather nice, so bear with me, if something in here sounds silly.

Examples:

[image: Juniata College letterhead]

[image: Brockhouse letterhead]

Comment: https://texblog.org/2012/03/07/writing-a-memo-in-latex/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an example you're emulating that you can point out?  Googling "latex fax cover sheet" found [this page](http://www.dsl.org/comp/templates/) with a plain TeX template but I'm not sure if the template classifies as "rather nice."

This might be a good application of ConTeXt here.

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for answering. Upon seeing your post I started to search a little, and I must admit it is my mistake. I'm actually looking for what is in the English world called a letterhead. In my part of europe, that goes under memorandum, and that was the main source of error. I'm putting a few examples that follow: http://www.juniata.edu/services/style/i/letterhead_guide.jpg http://www.cyanshiner.co.uk/images/print/stationery/letterhead/stationery_design_enlarged_letterhead_brockhouse.gif

Comment: No problem.  I took the liberty of adding those images to your question.  If you want to further edit the question to clarify you can.

Answer (score 3):

I use Context for letterheads, putting the text in two layers above a PDF letterhead that I had a graphic designer put together for me.  A simplified, commented version of the start of one of my documents goes as follows:

```
\input{client-details} % I keep information about clients and jobs in separate 
\input{job-details}    % files, so that, e.g., the contents of the invoice 
\def\DATE{17th November 2010} %  matches what the contract said.

\noheaderandfooterlines 
\definelayer[fullpage][position=no]
\definelayer[datestamp][x=143mm,y=81mm,height=2em,width=18em]

\starttext

\setlayer[fullpage][x=0pt,y=0pt]{% 
  \externalfigure[letterhead-v3-A4.pdf][width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight] 
}
\setlayer[datestamp][hoffset=0mm,voffset=0mm]{\DATE} 
  % datestamp layer allows exact placement of text on page independent of other layer
\setupbackgrounds[page][background={fullpage,datestamp}] 

\vbox to 16mm{~}

\getbuffer[CLIENTADDRESS] % \startbuffer[CLIENTADDRESS] is defined in client-details file

Dear \CLIENT, 

...
```

This is not really all that idiomatic (I use Plain Texisms where Context has its own abstractions, e.g., for handling variables like `\CLIENT` and `\DATE`) nor elegant - I'm sure I can clean up the way I place the date.  There more you can do with layers: you can have a letterhead on the front page, and a PDF background for the second and subsequent pages.  This is enoughn to get started with, though.

There's nothing all that fancy in the above: I think everything is documented in (i) *Context, An Excursion* (see [Context documentation](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Official_ConTeXt_Documentation) (ii) and on [the Context wiki's layers page](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layers).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a letter format [here](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-letterclass) you will find some. I think "newlfm" is easily customizable.